# Can't start local instance of Spark-Jobserver

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

So I'm trying to create a local instance of spark jobserver to test jobs on and I can't even get it to run.

So the first thing I do when I got into my vagrant instance is I start spark. I know this works because I submit jobs to spark with the submit-job utility it provides. I then go to my local spark-jobserver clone and run

```
vagrant@cassandra-spark:~/spark-jobserver$ sudo sbt
[info] Loading project definition from /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/project
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
Missing bintray credentials /root/.bintray/.credentials. Some bintray features depend on this.
[info] Set current project to root (in build file:/home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/)
> reStart /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/config/local.conf
[info] scalastyle using config /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/scalastyle-config.xml
[info] Processed 21 file(s)
[info] Found 0 errors
[info] Found 0 warnings
[info] Found 0 infos
[info] Finished in 35 ms
[success] created output: /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/job-server/target
[info] scalastyle using config /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/scalastyle-config.xml
[info] Processed 6 file(s)
[info] Found 0 errors
[info] Found 0 warnings
[info] Found 0 infos
[info] Finished in 6 ms
[success] created output: /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/job-server-extras/target
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[warn] Credentials file /root/.bintray/.credentials does not exist
[info] scalastyle using config /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/scalastyle-config.xml
[info] Processed 3 file(s)
[info] Found 0 errors
[info] Found 0 warnings
[info] Found 0 infos
[info] Finished in 8 ms
[success] created output: /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/job-server-api/target
[info] scalastyle using config /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/scalastyle-config.xml
[info] Processed 11 file(s)
[info] Found 0 errors
[info] Found 0 warnings
[info] Found 0 infos
[info] Finished in 7 ms
[success] created output: /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/akka-app/target
[info] scalastyle using config /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/scalastyle-config.xml
[info] Processed 3 file(s)
[info] Found 0 errors
[info] Found 0 warnings
[info] Found 0 infos
[info] Finished in 9 ms
[success] created output: /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/job-server-api/target
[info] scalastyle using config /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/scalastyle-config.xml
[info] Processed 11 file(s)
[info] Found 0 errors
[info] Found 0 warnings
[info] Found 0 infos
[info] Finished in 6 ms
[success] created output: /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/akka-app/target
[info] scalastyle using config /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/scalastyle-config.xml
[info] Processed 21 file(s)
[info] Found 0 errors
[info] Found 0 warnings
[info] Found 0 infos
[info] Finished in 2 ms
[success] created output: /home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/job-server/target
[info] Application job-server not yet started
[info] Starting application job-server in the background ...
job-server Starting spark.jobserver.JobServer.main(/home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/config/local.conf)
job-server[ERROR] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[warn] No main class detected
[info] Application job-server-extras not yet started
[info] Starting application job-server-extras in the background ...
job-server-extras Starting spark.jobserver.JobServer.main(/home/vagrant/spark-jobserver/config/local.conf)
job-server-extras[ERROR] Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[success] Total time: 6 s, completed Jun 12, 2015 2:28:32 PM
> job-server-extras[ERROR] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (spark.jobserver.JobServer$).
job-server-extras[ERROR] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
job-server-extras[ERROR] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

>
```

In another terminal I ssh into the vagrant instance and run

```
vagrant@cassandra-spark:~$ curl --data-binary @/home/vagrant/SQLJob/target/scala-2.10/CassSparkTest-a
ssembly-1.0.jar localhost:8090/jars
The requested resource could not be found.
```

This is what is in my config/local.conf

```
    # Template for a Spark Job Server configuration file
# When deployed these settings are loaded when job server starts
#
# Spark Cluster / Job Server configuration
spark {
  # spark.master will be passed to each job's JobContext
  master = "spark://192.168.10.11:7077"
  # master = "mesos://vm28-hulk-pub:5050"
  # master = "yarn-client"

  # Default # of CPUs for jobs to use for Spark standalone cluster
  job-number-cpus = 1



  # predefined Spark contexts
  # contexts {
  #   my-low-latency-context {
  #     num-cpu-cores = 1           # Number of cores to allocate.  Required.
  #     memory-per-node = 512m         # Executor memory per node, -Xmx style eg 512m, 1G, etc.
  #   }
  #   # define additional contexts here
  # }

  # universal context configuration.  These settings can be overridden, see README.md
  context-settings {
    num-cpu-cores = 1           # Number of cores to allocate.  Required.
    memory-per-node = 512m         # Executor memory per node, -Xmx style eg 512m, #1G, etc.

    spark.cassandra.connection.host = "127.0.0.1"

    # in case spark distribution should be accessed from HDFS (as opposed to being installed on every mesos slave)
    # spark.executor.uri = "hdfs://namenode:8020/apps/spark/spark.tgz"

    # uris of jars to be loaded into the classpath for this context. Uris is a string list, or a string separated by commas ','
    dependent-jar-uris = ["file:///home/vagrant/lib/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.3.0-M2-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

    # If you wish to pass any settings directly to the sparkConf as-is, add them here in passthrough,
    # such as hadoop connection settings that don't use the "spark." prefix
    passthrough {
      #es.nodes = "192.1.1.1"
    }
  }

  # This needs to match SPARK_HOME for cluster SparkContexts to be created successfully
  home = "/home/vagrant/spark"
}

# Note that you can use this file to define settings not only for job server,
# but for your Spark jobs as well.  Spark job configuration merges with this configuration file as defaults.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was, the server was starting correctly (although not logging correctly)

The problem was that I didn't have "/" at the end of the path passed to curl

so to fix it change the curl statement to this:

```
vagrant@cassandra-spark:~$ curl --data-binary @/home/vagrant/SQLJob/target/scala-2.10/CassSparkTest-a
ssembly-1.0.jar localhost:8090/jars
```